# Using apalike bibliography style in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, bibliography, pybtex

I do not manage to use the apalike bibliography style with sphinx. With directive

```
.. bibliography:: references.bib
   :style: apalike
```

I got the following error message:

> Extension error (sphinxcontrib.bibtex.domain):
> Handler <function env_updated at 0x7f1db5c96b80> for event 'env-updated' threw an exception (exception: plugin pybtex.style.formatting.apalike not found)
> Makefile:20: recipe for target 'html' failed
> make: *** [html] Error 2

Is there a workaround to this issue or an alternative style similar to apalike?

I would like to use a style such that citations look like [Author names, 2021].

Comment: It looks like the extension does not support `apalike`. See docs: https://sphinxcontrib-bibtex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#bibliography-style. You can define a custom style: https://sphinxcontrib-bibtex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#bibtex-custom-formatting

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to produce a custom apalike style and then publish sources here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the extension does not support apalike. See [documentation](https://sphinxcontrib-bibtex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#bibliography-style).

You can define a [custom style](https://sphinxcontrib-bibtex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#bibtex-custom-formatting).